# Difference between product and chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Hello fellow math people,

My question will turn out to be super dumb, but I just can’t see where my fault is.

I am following a proof (page 2, the lemma here [https://www.math.upenn.edu/~deturck/m425/m425-blackscholessol-16a.pdf](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Edeturck/m425/m425-blackscholessol-16a.pdf))
and basically the problem is the following:

We have a function $V(t, x)$ and we introduce $u(t, x) = exp(ax + bt)V(t, x)$

Then we want to find $dV/dt$ in terms of $du/dt$. Easy enough.

$V = exp(-(ax + bt))u$ so by the product rule, $dV/dt = exp(-(ax + bt))du/dt - b exp(-(ax + bt))u$

However, I initially tried to go with the chain rule and express dV/dt as dV/du du/dt which only gives the first term above. I am almost 100% certain my problem is lack of understanding of multidimensional chain rule, but I got myself quite confused thinking about this...

I initially mistakenly posted this on mathoverflow, and I was directed to include a $dV/dt * dt/dt$ term, but I’m not sure why this doesn’t cancel out the dV/dt we are looking for the in the first place

Comment: As in my comment https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368159/difference-between-product-and-chain-rule#comment928777_368159 to which you refer, I'm pretty sure you mean $\frac\partial{\partial u}V\cdot\frac\partial{\partial t} u$ (you have $t$'s in place of $u$'s).

Comment: I think the important thing to remember is that there really is no such thing as, say, $\frac\partial{\partial t}V$ by itself, even though we're used to writing it; we need to decide whether we mean to take the derivative of a 3-variable function $V(u, x, t)$ or of a 2-variable function $V(u(x, t), x, t)$.  Despite their notational similarity, these are different functions, and their derivatives are different; for example, $\frac\partial{\partial t}V(u, x, t) \ne \frac\partial{\partial t}V(u(x, t), x, t)$, and $\frac\partial{\partial u}V(u(x, t), x, t)$ doesn't even make sense.

Comment: A simplified, but mostly random, example:  $V(u, t) = u t$ and $u(t) = \sin(t)$.  Then $\frac\partial{\partial t}V(u, t)\bigr|_{(u, t) = (u(t_0), t_0)} = \frac\partial{\partial t}(u t)\bigr|_{(u, t) = (\sin(t_0), t_0)}$ equals $t_0$, but $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}V(u(t), t)\bigr|_{t = t_0} = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(t\sin(t))\bigr|_{t = t_0}$ equals $\sin(t_0) + t\cos(t_0)$.

Comment: (Oh, sorry.  I now see that you probably really did mean $\frac\partial{\partial t}V\cdot\frac{\partial t}{\partial t}$.  Again, the issue is that we start off trying to compute $\frac\partial{\partial t}V(u(x, t), x, t)$ on the left—derivative of 2-variable function—on the left, and we wind up computing it in terms of, among other things, $\frac\partial{\partial t}V(u, x, t)$—derivative of 3-variable function—on the right.)